# ARC seems to be releasing the view of my NSViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to solve a larger problem and I am tipping on the fact that ARC apparently is releasing the view to my NSViewController too early. I think :) So I created a simple app to reconstruct the situation.

I have a simple ARC Cocoa application. In the Window of the `MainMenu.xib` I hook up a `Custom View` to a `@property (strong) IBOutlet NSView *theView;` which is declared in the `AppDelegate.h`

In the `AppDelegate.m` I synthesize the property and then call the following:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    TestViewController *tvc =  [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
    [_theView addSubview:[tvc view]];
}
```

The `TestViewController`gets displayed in the `Custom View` - no problem. It contains one NSButton. It is hooked up to a method called `-(IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender` and one NSTextView which is also hooked up as an `IBOutlet`.

In the `TestViewController.h` I declare:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *theString;

-(IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender;
```

In the `TestViewController.m` I then do

```
@synthesize theString = _theString;
@synthesize textField = _textField;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
        _theString = @"Hello World";
    }

    return self;
}

-(IBAction)btnPressed:(id)sender
{
    [_textField setStringValue:_theString];
}
```

When I run the app and press the button it crashes. If I check it for zombies I receive the following:

```
#   Address Category    Event Type  RefCt   Timestamp   Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   0x7f97a3047560  TestViewController  Malloc  1   00:00.652.631   128 TestARC -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:]
1   0x7f97a3047560  TestViewController  Retain  2   00:00.653.088   0   TestARC -[TestViewController initWithNibName:bundle:]
2   0x7f97a3047560  TestViewController  Release 1   00:00.653.089   0   TestARC -[TestViewController initWithNibName:bundle:]
3   0x7f97a3047560  TestViewController  Retain  2   00:00.653.912   0   AppKit  -[NSNib instantiateNibWithOwner:topLevelObjects:]
4   0x7f97a3047560  TestViewController  Release 1   00:00.658.831   0   AppKit  -[NSNib instantiateNibWithOwner:topLevelObjects:]
5   0x7f97a3047560  TestViewController  Release 0   00:00.662.377   0   Foundation  -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]
6   0x7f97a3047560  TestViewController  Zombie  -1  00:01.951.377   0   AppKit  -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:]
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a property to hold the view controller.  Your controller currently has nothing to keep it alive past the end of the method that allocates it.

Add:

```
@property (strong) TestViewController *tvc;
```

Modify:

```
self.tvc =  [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
```

(I'm curious...what do you see as the point of creating a view controller if all you want is the view it contains?)

---

Concerning the general approach, it seems that this is more properly behavior that should be implemented using a container view controller.  That mechanism allows multiple view controllers to share the screen in an organized way.

Comment: I am using ViewControllers to load different views (and their respective methods) into the Custom View I have in the Main Window. I was wanting to use the Custom View as a "frame" for interchangeable content. Changing AppDelegate.h to `@property (strong) IBOutlet TestViewController *theView;` forces me to remove the `addSubview`, right? But that doesn't load TestViewController's view into the Custom View...

Comment: No, leave the `addSubview` if that's the way you want the design to work.  As I said, the `subviews` array will take care of retaining it.  It's only the lifecycle of the controller that was a problem in your original coding.  (The better supported way of getting what I think you want, though, is by creating a container view controller.  With that structure, there are defined methods for maintaining a parent/child controller relationship.)

Comment: if I leave the addSubview line as is. Then I get an error `No visible @interface for 'TestViewController' declares the selector 'addSubview'.`

Comment: Sorry...I made a wrong assumption about how you were using the property you have defined.  Instead of changing what you had as a property, add a new one for the controller and assign it to that when you create it.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have another question to my general approach: In my app I have two "sections". Each section is separate from each other, however bother are to be display next to each other. That is why I placed two custom views onto the main window and hooked them each up to views of the two ViewControllers. I wanted to logically and "physically" separte the code. Is this the "wrong" way to implement what I was trying to do?

Comment: You don't need to *change* your existing IOButlet; you new that to be able to add the subview. But you need to add another ivar or property to hold on to the controller as well.

Comment: @BJ Homer -- Yes, my mistake...I'm so used to people writing `[self.view addSubview:...];` that I didn't focus on the actual use of the outlet and assumed it was connected the the view being grabbed out of its controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an ivar or property to hold the TextViewController.  Currently, the only reference to it is going away at the end of `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` which causes it to be deallocated.

That's bad, because your button needs the controller to be around to handle the button press. The view doesn't hold on to it's controller, as that would cause a retain cycle. So you are responsible for keeping the controller around if you don't want your button talking to a deallocated object.